# How to call a method from extended class with class name in PHP

Tags: php, class, methods, extended-properties

Let's say I have 3 classes and methods in it;

> file1.php

```
class A
{
  public function insert()
   {
     /* some code to do something with DB */
   }
}
```

> file2.php

*require file1.php*

```
class B extends A
{
  public function sample()
   {
      /* doing something random */
   }
}
```

> file3.php

*require file2.php*

```
class C extends B
{
 public function something()
  {
   $this->insert();  //In here I want to use it like $this->A->insert(); OR $A->insert(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Whats problem in `$this->insert();`

Comment: _In here I want to use it like $this->A->insert(); OR $A->insert();_ Isn't possible with inheritance. You should just call `$this->insert();`

Comment: @ZainFarooq I want to make it looks like more pretty. This is a big application so I want that particular line like $db->insert(); instead of $this->insert();

Comment: @Daan What is the proper way of using class like this?   I want to use the method with class name somehow...  any workaround using alias or something?

Comment: You can inject class A into class C. See also Dependency Injection. <= no inheritance.

Comment: You can use static functions to call functions with class name

Comment: @ZainFarooq Can't use static calls since I am using mysqli instance in insert() method of class A.

Comment: So, why can't we use instance of mysqli in a static function?

Comment: What do you mean by that? What makes you think that you can use any `mysqli` function in a static context? All need to be run from an initialized database connection

Comment: `class C extends B
{
 public function something()
  {
   A::insert(); 
  }
}`

Comment: You shouldn't use extends unless class A, B and C all interacts with the database/query, where it makes sense to only use `$this->`. You are probably better of with dependency injection if you feel the need to specify the class name when calling the methods.